# increase the touchable area with hitSlop (React-native-popup-menu)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I'm using react-native-popup-menu but I'm trying to increase the area where the user can click for the menu option to be triggered. I've gone through the documentation and there is information about `TouchableOpactiy` but it seems to be about styling it but I feel like I'm also not understanding it.

I have a component that I'm passing `OptionsMenu` as a prop:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{alignContent: 'flex-end', paddingRight:10}} hitSlop={{bottom: 50, top: 50, left: 50, right: 50 }}>
   //I know using hitSlop here is wrong and it is not triggering anything here. Just showing what I have.
      {OptionMenu}
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

and in another screen I have it set to

```
<Menu>

    <MenuTrigger>
        <Svg
            viewBox="0 0 64 512"
            height={34}
            width={10}
            fill='#7b8794'
        >
            <Path d="M32 224c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32-32-14.3-32-32 14.3-32 32-32zM0 136c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32-14.3-32-32-32-32 14.3-32 32zm0 240c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32s32-14.3 32-32-14.3-32-32-32-32 14.3-32 32z" />
        </Svg>
    </MenuTrigger>


    <MenuOptions>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => handleInsert(item, index)} text='Duplicate' />
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => handleRemove(index)}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
    </MenuOptions>

</Menu>
```

I'm not understanding where I can pass `hitSlop` in to be able to increase the `touchable` area to trigger the `MenuOptions`.

Comment: you could use `triggerTouchable` to pass the prop to touchable. https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/doc/api.md#custom-styles-1  or make your own `TriggerTouchableComponent`

Comment: so I wrap the `<Menu> jsx with `TouchableOpacity` jsx and pass `triggerTouchable` into `TouchableOpacity` as a prop? What would I set `triggerTouchable` to? I'm sorry I'm just so confused

Comment: sorry, I confused trigger with menu option, but check the doc - there is also `optionTouchable` and see it in official example https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/examples/TouchableExample.js

Comment: So I add `optionTouchable` to `MenuOption` but I'm confused on how can I pass `hitSlop` to it? I'm sorry I'm still learning javascript and the documentation is a little confusing to me. I just want to make the area that users can press for the menu button to be triggered bigger.